# Uploading file with MVC

Tags: java, file, spring-mvc, file-upload

I am using spring MVC!!!

I have one form on my website, this form is supposed to get the file from a website user, and then store it in central database. This form looks something like this:

```
<form action="getFile"> 
   <input type = "file" name="file">
</form>
```

So in the upper form, the user should drag, or place the file. And in the controller below I am trying to get a file, and best would be if I can somehow make that file type File in java.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/valueOfFileWithForm")
public static String getFile(HttpServletRequest req){
  /// and here should happen something like this, as we do with strings or ints...
  File file = req.getParameter("file");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use something like,

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/valueOfFileWithForm")
  public static String getFile(@RequestPart(value = "file") MultipartFile file)
```

And then pass the "file" parameter to a method like this:

```
public String saveFile(MultipartFile file) throws FileNotFoundException {

        try {
            List<String> nameAndFormat = getNameAndFormat(
                    Objects.requireNonNull(file.getOriginalFilename()).
                            replace(" ", "-"));
            String name = nameAndFormat.get(0);

            String format = nameAndFormat.get(1);

            if (file.isEmpty()) {
                throw new FileNotFoundException(file.getName());
            }

            if (!Arrays.asList(allowedFormats).contains(nameAndFormat.get(1).toLowerCase())) {
                throw new IOException();
            }

            String directoryName = makeDirectory(
                    Constants.ROOT_USER_DIRECTORY + Constants.ROOT_STORAGE + Constants.IMAGE_DIRECTORY)
                    .getAbsolutePath();

            timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(new Date());
            String updatedTimeStamp = timeStamp.replaceAll(" ", "-");
            updatedTimeStamp = updatedTimeStamp.replaceAll(":", "-");

            fileName = directoryName + "/" + updatedTimeStamp + "_" + "pic" + "." + format;

            File convertedFile = new java.io.File(fileName);

            if (convertedFile.exists()) {
                convertedFile.mkdirs();
            }

            file.transferTo(convertedFile);
            byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
            Path path = Paths.get(fileName);
            Files.write(path, bytes);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());

        }

        return fileName;

    }
```

this part of code "Constants.ROOT_USER_DIRECTORY + Constants.ROOT_STORAGE + Constants.IMAGE_DIRECTORY)" specify your directory to upload file

Comment: Please Remember its important to use MultipartFile to upload your file...

Comment: This works, with some minor modifications for my case. Thanks :)

Comment: @DaniloCongradac